# Cannot update a table column with uppercase values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have used the below SQL query to update an existing DB table's column with uppercase values.

```
update table_name set column_name=UPPER('value');
```

When I run this query in a ***local DB***, then the column gets updated with uppercase values. But when I executed this query on a ***remote host DB***, then the table column was updated in lowercase values. What could be the reason for this? Am I doing anything wrong here? Is there any other methods available in SQL to update a table column with uppercase data?

Comment: What are the local DB and the remote host DB using? Same DBMS, same version?

Comment: Sorry, I have forgotten to mention it :). I'm having MySQL 5.5.31 locally and having MySQL 5.1.48 in remote computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually convert into `latin1` and then try to insert.

```
UPPER(CONVERT('value' USING latin1))
```